# Not able to connect to SQL Server 2012 Mangement Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2012

My instance name is `MSSQLSERVER` and while I connect to Management Studio, I use `.\MSSQLSERVER` to login. I have gone through all the threads here but everyone is suggesting to enable tcp, pipes, shared memory which I have done and restarted the server too. Also I am using .\instance name as suggested. But still can't connect, and I get the following error

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to .\MSSQLSERVER.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 87)

It would be great if someone could help me with this

Comment: Why don't you use just `MSSQLSERVER` ?

Comment: Is the SQL Server and SSMS where you are trying to connect from on the same server?

Comment: are you sure it's a named-instance? any chance of uploading a screenshot?

Comment: also can you please confirm if sqlservices is running with a valid login account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MSSQLSERVER` is the SQL Server **service name** for the **default** instance which is the instance *without* any instance name - so to connect to this (unnamed) default instance, just use

```
.
(local)
localhost
your-machine-name
```

**without** any "instance" name (since there *is NO instance name*)

Comment: @mounika: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Comment: Sorry didn't know that I could accept the answer!! Did it and Thanks again :)

Comment: @mounika: that's okay - we all live and learn - thanks for accepting, I gave you an upvote on your question in return